# Cant get model fields to display on the page

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm using this model:

```
 public class ListCoins
{
    public Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,float>> listCoins{ get; set; }
}
```

when I try to display them in the view using this method:

```
model IEnumerable<Crytocurrency_Web___Main.JResult.ListCoins>

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
 <h4>Coin Value: @ViewBag.WalletValue</h4>
<table class="table">
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayName("Name"))
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayName("CoinValue")
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayName("CoinAmmount")
    </th>
    <th></th>
</tr>

@for (var i = 0; i < Model.ElementAt(i).listCoins.Count; i++)
{

foreach (var coin in Model.ElementAt(i).listCoins)
{
    <p>@coin.Key + " " + @coin.Value)</p>

}

}
```

i get the error on the line:

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.ElementAt(i).listCoins.Count; i++)
```

but in the controller i have checked that count is over one:

```
        int counter = listOfCoins.Count;
```

which equals four and all the data is there.

i may just be displaying them wrong but i cant figure it out

controller code:

```
        List<ListCoins> newListCoins = new List<ListCoins>();
        foreach (var coin in listOfCoins)
        {
            using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
            {
                var json = client.DownloadString(
                    "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemulti?fsyms=" + queryString + "&tsyms=" +
                    queryString);
                var result = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert
                    .DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, float>>>(json);
                newListCoins.Add(new ListCoins
                {
                    listCoins = result,
                });
            }
        }


        return View(newListCoins.ToList());
```

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: @w0051977 System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.'

Comment: OK.  I have provided an answer.  Let me know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to use: Model.ElementAt(i).  You can do this:

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.listCoins.Count; i++)
```

rather than this:

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.ElementAt(i).listCoins.Count; i++)
```

You can then loop through all of the elements in listCoins and display the values in the view.

Comment: i then get "The name listCoin does not exist in this current context"

Comment: Thanks for the help.

"IEnumerable<ListCoin> does not contain a definition for list coins and no extension method 'listCoins' accepting a first argument of type 'IEnumerable<ListCoin>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 0):

You are getting `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` because you are trying to access an item in the collection with an index which does not exist!

This part in your for loop

```
i < Model.ElementAt(i).listCoins.Count
```

You are trying to loop until n where n is the Count of your child property `listCoins` of each item.

Your view is strongly typed to a collection of `ListCoins`. So Your outer loop should be from `0` to `Model.Count`

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{    
    foreach (var coin in Model.ElementAt(i).listCoins)
    {
        <p>@coin.Key + " " + @coin.Value)</p>    
    }    
}
```

Here , the `coin.Value` **is again another dictionary**(`Dictionary<string,float>`), so you probably want to loop through the items in that as well.

I feel the `foreach` version could be more readable.

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    foreach (var coin in item.listCoins)
    {
        <h1>@coin.Key</h1>
        foreach (var v in coin.Value)
        {
            <p>@v.Key - @v.Value</p>
        }
    }
}
```